# Erro na instalação do React Native

Tags: android, python, react, react-native

Estou tentando configurando o ambiente do react native em meu computador.
Conseguir instalar o gerenciador de pacotes choco. Porém quando tento instalar o python2 com o comando: `choco install python2` aparece esta mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o windows 10 64 com Java Skd e JRe 1.8
Observação importante: conseguir instalar o nodejs com este comando: `choco install nodejs.install`

Comment: E por que não baixa o instalador do Python e instala normalmente?

Comment: é altamente recomendado usar o gerenciador de pacote Choco para montar o ambiente React Native. Porém. vou testar sua ideia. Grato!

Comment: Que besteira. Python é Python, independente de como você instala.

Comment: Instalei o Python na tora..Vou verificar se não interfere no ambiente do React Native...

Comment: Não tem como interferir. É a mesma coisa. Só uma dica: se você quiser realmente resolver o problema com o choco, é uma boa postar o conteúdo do tal log de erros que é falado no CMD. Só lendo uma mensagem de erro genérica é impossível te ajudar. O log existe pra ser usado =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque não utiliza o [Create React Native App](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#getting-started) ou [Expo.io](https://expo.io/). Ambos não necessitam de setar um ambiente com GBs e mais GBs de bibliotecas. Não é bem a solução para a sua pergunta mas é uma possibilidade. Em poucos minutos você consegue iniciar um projeto React Native.

Comment: Mas fica refém dos pacotes disponibilizados pelo expo, além de perder desempenho com relação a um nativo, sendo recomendado apenas para projetos pequenos

Comment: Sim, tem de ser considerados os trade-offs dessa opção, mas em relação a desempenho, é o mesmo visto que tb é React-Native, na pergunta ele não está comparando React-Native com nativo puro. Sendo assim, a única diferença entre create-react-native-app e react-native é que só se pode utilizar libs de javascript puro, e caso necessário maiores customizações você sempre poderá ejetar o projeto e ter essas customizações.

Comment: Não, o desempenho do Expo pro React-native puro não é o mesmo, pois o Expo adiciona uma camada, no expo é como se o APP fosse emulado pela aplicação do Expo